# MVC ASP.NET CORE Register On Key Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

as the title states. I am trying to protect registration and make it only based on invitation. Therefore i am protecting it by a key. 
Basically every time there is a registration. User filles out all the regular stuff. Email, username, password. I want to add a key. Not KeyId but the guid accessKey. How can integrate it into the registration form and check if the key actually exists before completing user registration. Is there a better way of doing it? Like creating a registration link that will work only on one user.

```
public class User : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser       
      {           
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        //Key assigned
        public Key Key { get; set; }
        public int? KeyId { get; set; }

      }
    public class Key
     {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Guid AccessKey { get; set; }
        public bool Status { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Created { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
        // User assigned to keys
        public User Owner { get; set; }
        public int? OwnerId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You could generate these random keys and store them in the db, with both an expiration date and if it was used already or not. The codes could come as a simple queryString param to your `Register` action, where prior to saving (or even showing the view) you would validate it. You might also have to consider concurrency issues, as multiple users could use the same code at the same time..

Comment: Thanks, I was able to figure out.